# how to force insert statement to run without inserting any records in values clause

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

i have an situation where i have a following table.

```
    create table Bulk_Data
    (
    id int identity(1,1),
    UserName varchar(100) not null default 'default value ',
    iPartitionID int null
    )
```

also i have an Insert trigger on Bulk_Data.

```
create trigger dbo.Bulk_Data_IU on Bulk_Data 
AFTER INSERT  
AS Begin

    Merge Bulk_Data p1 
    using Bulk_Data p2 on p1.id = p2.id
    when matched then 
        update set p1.iPartitionID = right(p2.id,1);

end
```

condition in above table is like 
i have 3 column which are not depended on any values.
1] id is identity auto increment column
2] UserName is set to be default values
3] iPartitionID is based on insert in Trigger.

so my question is how should i insert the records say suppose i do not required
to insert any values in #2 i.e. in column 2 so how should i fire the insert command on table.

because insert command is important for me as i have created Insert trigger.

when i run

```
insert Bulk_Data(UserName) values('Suraj Sheikh')
```

it works fine but what if i don't want to insert any UserName.

is this possible ?

please help me out here.

Comment: Why can't you just execute the merge statement on its own? Why do you want to calculate the `iPartitionID` column (every row) for each insert? You can use the `inserted` table to figure out what rows to modify or you could use a calculated column `iPartitionID as right(pd.id, 1)` instead of a trigger.

Comment: it is because i want to make the process automated.

Comment: A calculated column is automated without the need of a trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a computed column instead of a trigger that updates all rows for each insert.

```
create table Bulk_Data
    (
    id int identity(1,1),
    UserName varchar(100) not null default 'default value ',
    iPartitionID as id % 10 persisted
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "Instead OF" trigger rather than using "AFTER INSERT" trigger.

INSTEAD-OF triggers are very powerful objects in SQL Server. They allow the developer to divert the database engine to do something different than what the user is trying to do.

In this way, when an insert query is fired on that table, insertion will not happen and whatever statements are written in trigger will actually applied to db.

Limitation - INSTEAD OF DELETE/UPDATE triggers cannot be defined on a table that has a foreign key with a cascade on DELETE/UPDATE action defined but Insert Trigger can be defined.

Comment: yes right but can we run the insert statement without inserting any records i mean only insert statemtent.

Comment: Don't write any code to insert in Instead of trigger. So nothing will be inserted in table.